# Cross-domain: Parse error / Failed to load resource with JSON Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain

in our company we have a proxy to send SMS to mobile phones and i'm having issue to get a response iguess due to some cross-domain issues...because the app is on myCompanyurl.com
whereas the sms app is on myProxyCompanyurl.com

```
jQuery.get("http://myproxycompanyurl.com/proxy.php?type=text&mesg=Hello&output=json&number=000000000&callback=?",
      function(response) {
           console.log('test');
           console.log(response);
      }
);
```

in my debug console:

```
> test
> Failed to load resource: cancelled
```

if I use getJSON

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://myproxycompanyurl.com/proxy.php?type=text&mesg=Hello&output=json&number=000000000&callback=?",
      function(response) {
           console.log('test');
           console.log(response);
      }
);
```

in my debug console:

```
> Parse Error
```

the point is that in both case the sms app works...i receive the sms on my phone, but the  problem is i cannot get a response so i can send a message/alert to my users that everything went fine...

Comment: The parse error is due to unmatched brackets: you open one `{` and you close two `}`.

Comment: sorry my typo here but in my code was right

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this error?

Answer (score 1):

The response from your MyProxyCompanyUrl.com in "JSON", which will throw XMLHttpRequest cannot load [http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=marketdatav2](http://myproxycompanyurl.com/proxy.php?type=text&mesg=Hello&output=json&number=000000000&callback=?). No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource, due to cross domain issue.

you can change your proxy site to return a "JSONP" instead which can be loaded without any issues

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://myproxycompanyurl.com/proxy.php?type=text&mesg=Hello&output=json&number=000000000&callback=?',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

});

or if you don't have access to your proxy site, you can make use of third parties to do that for you. For ex: [jsonp.guffa.com](http://jsonp.guffa.com/) and your proxy jsonp url for this site will be http://jsonp.guffa.com/Proxy.ashx?url=http://myproxycompanyurl.com/proxy.php?type=text&mesg=Hello&output=json&number=000000000&callback=?

Answer (score -1):

Well, the error message in #2 says it all...your server is returning invalid JSON, so it can't be parsed.

Take a look at the actual response text in something like this: http://json.parser.online.fr/ and see where the problem is.